# What does it mean two meshes are combinatorially equivalent?

Tags: geometry

What does it mean two meshes are *combinatorially equivalent*?

Does it mean they are congruent? What is the difference between congruence and combinatorial equivalency? I'm a non mathematician so I would very much appreciate an answer ready for kids to understand it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer. Consider you label each triangle of a mesh, and then write down which pairs of triangles have an edge in common. The information you have written down is the combinatoric information. Tow meshes are equivalent if you could find a labeling such that the resulting adjacent pairs are the same. The meshes themselves might be very different: different lengths of triangle edges, different positions in space, different angles between planes and so on. But all that is irrelevant from a combinatoric point of view.